# Joining of Four or More Tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to join 5 tables and I have written a query Like this but I am getting invalid Identifier mvk when I run this query.

```
SELECT *
  FROM CBH.MARKETINGCBH mcbh
  JOIN CBH.MCBH_INTERESSES mi on mi.MARKETINGCBHID = mcbh.MARKETINGCBHID
  JOIN CBH.INTERESSES i on i.INTERESSESID = mi.INTERESSESID
  JOIN CBH.MAILING_VIA_KANAAL mvk on mvk.MAILINGVIAKANAALID = i.MAILINGVIAKANAALID
  JOIN CBH.RESPONS_INTERESSES ri on  ri.INTERESSESID=mvk.INTERESSESID 
 WHERE mcbh.CBHID = '10351720'
   AND mvk.MAILINGKANAALCODE = 'EMA'
   AND i.SOORTINTERESSECODE = 'INT'
   AND mi.DATUM > (SELECT mi2.DATUM 
                     FROM CBH.MARKETINGCBH mcbh2
                     JOIN CBH.MCBH_INTERESSES mi2 on mi2.MARKETINGCBHID = mcbh2.MARKETINGCBHID
                     JOIN CBH.INTERESSES i2 on i2.INTERESSESID = mi2.INTERESSESID
                    WHERE i2.SOORTINTERESSECODE = 'DES'
                      AND mcbh2.CBHID = '10351720' 
                      AND i2.MAILINGVIAKANAALID = i.MAILINGVIAKANAALID);
```

Comment: check for name of ojbects.

Comment: Error says that it is not able to find what `mvk` is, however I see you assigning the alias. Please check which line is giving the error and let us know.

Comment: can you explain???

Comment: JOIN CBH.RESPONS_INTERESSES ri on  ri.INTERESSESID=mvk.INTERESSESID  this line  is giving me the error when i am executing without this line it is working fine

Comment: Please add the full, actual error message to the question. It won't just say "mvk", it will give the table and column. Does your MAILING_VIA_KANAA table actually have a column called INTERESSESID? If you think it does then add the structures of all the tables to the question, e.g. the output of `describe MAILING_VIA_KANAA`.

Answer (score 0):

Was your code copied and pasted from anywhere? I'd suggest replacing " mvk " with something brand new throughout the query as a test. I've seen stray invisible characters get thrown in. Make sure you delete all spaces surrounding the alias as well.